# Starting X remotely on the remote host

Tags: ssh, xorg

I want to remotely start xserver on the remote machine.

If I type "startx" directly on the host machine (i.e. using physical keyboard), the xserver starts as expected. However, when I try to do that over ssh with the same user this does not work.

I get the following server error:

```
      (EE) xf86OpenConsole: Cannot open virtual console 7 (Permission denied)
```

sudo startx still works even remotely.

What is preventing xserver to start on remote connections? And how to go around this?

Comment: i think it's simply the two things are mutually incompatible. ssh has text-only support no remote desktop support. startx is probably trying to send somthing over the connection that a text-only pipe cannot support.

Comment: I'd use input methods of the physical host then. I just want to have a possibility to remotely start X. The only reasonable explanation would be that remote user can't trigger access to host's input/output devices on kernel level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run X, you need read/write access to a `tty` device you want the X to run on (in your case `tty7`). In the past `Xorg` used to run as root, and the `/usr/bin/Xorg` binary had SUID bit set, so there was no problem with permissions whatsoever.

Recently Linux distributions started to switching to rootless/SUIDless `Xorg` binary, so the X server has the same permissions as the user. This isn't a problem for user logged in on the physical (`tty`) console, because `login` process changes the ownership of the `tty` device to the logged-in user.

There are several ways to work around this.

The cleanest one is possibly giving Xorg its SUID bit back:

`sudo chmod u+s /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg`

Answer (score 0):

Read `man ssh`, and use either the `-X` or `-Y` options.

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/ssh.1.html

Comment: -X      Enables X11 forwarding.  This can also be specified on a per-host basis in a configuration file.

-Y      Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls.

Comment: This does not solve my problem. I do not want to forward X. I only want to remotely turn on X via ssh.  From that point on, X server should run locally on the host machine. My workaround is currently to start one of display managers as root and then login.

Comment: `-X` is great for forwarding an *existing* X server, but does nothing toward *starting* a remote X server.